# Why values of i and j are 2 after the execution of statement " j= i++ + ++i"?

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment, associativity

The code I used is

int i=0, j=0;
j=i++ + ++i;

And the output I got is i=2 and j=2

Could anyone explain how this happens!

Comment: because `i++` is increased after evaluation, and `++i` is increased before evaluation

Comment: Can you [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (or the duplicate) if one of them solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is evaluated in below steps:

**Step 1 :** j = i++ + ++i; =>  j = 0 + ++i; **step result** i = 1 and j = 0 (post increment will update the value but returns the old value)

**Step 2 :** j = 0 + ++i; => j = 0 + 2; **step result** i = 2 and j = 0 (pre increment will update the value and returns the updated value)

**Step 3 :** j = 0 + 2; => j = 2; **step result** i = 2 and j = 2 (direct addition and assign value to j)

Answer (score 2):

`i++` will "retrieve" 0 and then add 1 to `i`. `++i` will add 1 to `i` and then retrieve its value. Thus, this is equivalent to `j = 0 + 2`. It also adds 1 to `i` twice. Hence, `i = 2` and `j = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

i++ increments the value of i and returns the previous value it held and ++i increments the value and returns the new value. So in your equation the i++ increments i by 1 and returns the previous value 0. And as i is already incremented by 1 so now value of i is 1. Then this i will be incremented in ++i and return value will be the new value 2. So 0+2 is the value of j in the equation.